# Why are empty items in my array and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I am using Visual Studio Code. I am trying to return an array with only odd numbers using JavaScript. This is the code:

```js
function oddCouple(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
      delete arr[i];
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(oddCouple([2, 6, 7, 0, 1, 3, 7, 5]));
```

This is what I am getting. I do not want the empty items, just odd numbers.

```
[ <2 empty items>, 7, <1 empty item>, 1, 3, 7, 5 ]
```

Comment: You can't use `delete` to remove items in your array

Comment: That is technically incorrect. `delete` will remove the time, it just won't restructure the array (remove the slot/index the item was in), which I'm sure is what you are referring to. But the item itself (the data in the slot/index) is technically removed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `splice()` instead of delete because `delete` doesn't change the length of the array. But be careful using `splice()` in a `for` loop because you alter the array as you're looping through it, which doesn't work well.

An alternative is to loop backwards:

```js
function oddCouple(arr) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(oddCouple([2, 6, 7, 0, 1, 3, 7, 5]));
```

Of course a still better alternative is to use `filter()`, but note this doesn't change the original array.

```js
function oddCouple(arr) {
  return arr.filter(i => i % 2)  
}

console.log(oddCouple([2, 6, 7, 0, 1, 3, 7, 5]));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `delete` function removes the content of the item but keeps an empty slot.

You need the `splice` method to remove an element without leaving an empty slot.

```
arr.splice(i, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) deletes a property of an object. This is the index with the value for an array. The result is a [sparse array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#Trailing_commas_in_literals).

For getting an array without some items, you could filter the array.

```js
function oddCouple(array) {
    return array.filter(v => v % 2);
}

console.log(oddCouple([2, 6, 7, 0, 1, 3, 7, 5]));
```

Or if you need the same array reference, then you could use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and iterate the array from the end, because the index is changing after splicing the item.

```js
function oddCouple(array) {
    var i = array.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return array;
}

console.log(oddCouple([2, 6, 7, 0, 1, 3, 7, 5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the array by filtering truthy values:

```js
function oddCouple(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
      delete arr[i];
    }
  }
  return arr.filter(r=>r);
}

console.log(oddCouple([2, 6, 7, 0, 1, 3, 7, 5]));
```

Rather, I can do simply:

```js
const arr = [2,6,7,0,1,3,7,5]
console.log(arr.filter(r=>r%2!=0))
//or,
console.log(arr.filter(r=>r%2)) // !=0
```